# Handlebars does not output anything

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, handlebars.js, yeoman, bower

At the start of the file I define Handlebars etc.:

```
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

At the end of the `index.html`-file I pull in my Handlebars-file:

```
<!-- build:js({app,.tmp}) scripts/main.js -->
<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/serverHandler.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/driver.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

The file with the Handlebars-related code is `driver.js`. It looks like this:

```
driver = {
    someBoolean : false,
    name : null,
    startTime: new Date(),
    position : null
};

source   = $('#drive-buttons-template').html();
template = Handlebars.compile(source);
template(driver);
```

The template is in the `index.html`-file, and is between the loading of the Handlebars.js-file, and my files:

```
<script id="drive-buttons-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
{{#if someBoolean}} <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop" aria-hidden="true"></span> Start

{{else}} <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" aria-hidden="true"</span> Stop {{/if}}                           
</button> </script>
```

I've tried compiling it on [TryHandlebars](http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/), and it works there, which makes me think that I have something wrong in my setup. When I load the page, it gives me no errors, but does not show anything either. I can use Handlebars-methods etc. from the console, but it doesn't change anything.

Hopefully this isn't just me having missed something essential, but that may very well be. 
All help is greatly appriciated. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**
Some experimenting in the console:
I can access `template`, `driver` and `source`. A call to `template(driver)` returns the right HTML, but the website isn't updated.

It may not have been clear, but I use Grunt for a local development environment, and Handlebars is installed with Bower. The Gruntfile is produced by Yeoman.

Comment: Is it because of the missing `>` on the line that loads bootstrap.js?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in my question. Fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution with the last line of [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aybalasubramanian/N2b5M/1/). I gave the tag where the template was an ID, and used:

```
$('#tagIDName').append(template(driver));
```

instead of just `template(driver);`